# How do I upgrade IE 10 to IE 11 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-11

I have a user with a windows 8 x64 laptop running IE 10. We would like to upgrade the browser to IE 11. I checked the "about Internet Explorer" and install new versions automatically is checked. I cannot find anywhere on MS website to download an installer for windows 8 IE 11. I found a few updates to IE 11 for win8.1 but that does not help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows 10 cannot exist on Windows 8.1, IE 11 is built into it, if you have IE 10 then you don't actually have Windows 8.  It is literally not possible for IE 10 to run on Windows 8.1 likewise its not possible for IE 11 to run on Windows 8.0 ( nor Windows 10 ).

Comment: That explains a lot. I was under the false presumption everything on our network has been upgraded past that. Thank you.

Comment: 'Winver' to confirm my statements

Answer (score 1):

It's strange. Please know that IE 11 is preinstalled in Windows 8.1, please let your user to make sure about it.

If he mean the Internet Explorer Metro version, please let him check if the IE11 is turned on in Features and programs:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/install-ie#ie=ie-11

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8.0 only supports IE10 (in desktop and "Metro" mode), not IE11 (or any other Microsoft browser). To install IE11, upgrade the machine to Windows 8.1.

You should upgrade to 8.1 anyhow; support for Windows 8.0 has ended already. From https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15347/announcing-windows-8-1-support-lifecycle-policy (emphasis added):

> Windows 8.1 builds on the foundation of Windows 8 and includes many enhancements and great new features in key areas like personalization, search, the built-in apps, Windows Store experience, and cloud connectivity. Windows 8.1 also introduces new manageability, mobility, security, user experience and networking capabilities for businesses. The lifecycle of Windows 8.1 will remain under the same lifecycle policy as Windows 8 with support ending 1/10/2023. **Windows 8 customers now have two years to move to Windows 8.1 *after its General Availability* to continue to remain supported under the Windows 8 lifecycle.** With the availability of Windows 8.1, it is time to start planning your deployment, and there are deployment tools and guidance available to help make these updates seamless for customers.

Windows 8.1's General Availability date was October 17, 2013 (per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1)); this date is now **more than three years ago** and Windows 8.0 has thus been unsupported for over 12 months. Therefore, your user is *not receiving critical security updates*, which is an even bigger problem than being on IE10 in general.